# laravel update table returns error

Tags: laravel

I have the following issue when I try to update the laravel table I send my data via ajax everything is good. But the update returns an error.

the following function receives the data and updates the table.

```
public function saveCalendar(Request $request) {
    $calendar = $request->calendar;
    $apartment_id = $request->apartment_id;
    apartments::where('Apartment_ID', $apartment_id)->update(array('calendar' => $calendar));
    $confirmation = 'Календара е запазен успешно !';
    return $confirmation;
}
```

I also tried this query:

```
    apartments::where('Apartment_ID', $apartment_id)->update('calendar' => $calendar);
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Error is because update function accepts array. Correct syntax is

```
apartments::where('Apartment_ID', $apartment_id)->update(['calendar' => $calendar]);
```

Also the correct syntax for fetching resquest inputs are

```
$calendar = $request->input('calendar'); 
$apartment_id = $request->input('apartment_id');
```

Comment: found the mistake I am missing a column updated_at in the table and becouse of that the query was not working.

Comment: Yeah tnx for the tip. And for the help :)